# Why does runif() not predict the interval maximum value?

Tags: r

I was [responding](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/6y93j8/if_you_were_to_randomly_find_a_playing_card_on/dmlyq7p/) to question posed over at [Reddit AskScience](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/6y93j8/if_you_were_to_randomly_find_a_playing_card_on/) and I came across something odd with respect to the functionality of `runif()`. I was attempting to sample a set from 1 to 52 uniformly. My first thought was to use runif():

```
as.integer(runif(n, min = 1, max = 52))
```

However, I found that the operation never produced a value of 52. For example:

```
length(unique(as.integer(runif(1000000, 1, 52))))
[1] 51
```

For my purposes, I just turned to `sample()` instead:

```
sample(52, n, replace = TRUE)
```

In the runif() documentation it states:

> runif will not generate either of the extreme values unless max = min or max-min is small compared to min, and in particular not for the default arguments.

I'm wondering why `runif()` acts this way. It seems like it should be able to produce the 'extreme values' from the set if its attempting to generate samples uniformly.  Is this a feature, and why?

Comment: The probability of getting 52 exactly is 0. Why are you surprised at not observing a prespecified event of probability 0?

Comment: The uniform distribution is continuous - the probability of sampling any given value in a continuous distribution is zero, it's only over *intervals* of the distribution that you get finite probabilities - so you're very unlikely to end up sampling `52.000000...`, even if there are no implementation quirks.

Comment: See this discussion: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27431/uniform-distribution-generation-of-extreme-values-in-r

Comment: Surely I made some mistakes on my initial attempt to perform the sampling. This lead me to the more interesting question for why runif() does not generate the extreme values. Ben Bolker answered this nicely.

Comment: An alternative that will work with `runif` is `ceiling(runif(100, min = 0, max = 52))`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is indeed a feature.  The [C source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/nmath/runif.c#L34) of `runif` contains the following C code:

```
/* This is true of all builtin generators, but protect against
       user-supplied ones */
    do {u = unif_rand();} while (u <= 0 || u >= 1);
return a + (b - a) * u;
```

this implies that `unif_rand()` *could* return 0 or 1, but `runif()` is engineered to skip those (unlikely) cases.

My guess would be that this is done to protect user code that would fail in the edge cases (values exactly on the boundaries of the range).

This feature was [implemented by Brian Ripley on Sep 19 2006](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/9df0e77e8bb04fb21de8321834e03f99c24cdb6c) (from the comments it seems that `0<u<1` is automatically true of the built-in uniform generator, but might not be true for user-supplied ones).

`sample(1:52,size=n,replace=TRUE)` is an idiomatic (although not necessarily the most efficient) way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3):

`as.integer` works like `trunc`. It will form an integer by truncating the given value toward 0. And since values can't exceed 52 ([see Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065709/7128934)) they will always be truncated to a value between 1 and 51.

You would see different result with `floor` (or [`ceiling`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065633/why-does-runif-not-predict-the-interval-maximum-value/46065742#comment79111126_46065633)). **Note that** you have to adjust the `max` of `runif` by adding `1` (or adjust `min` in case of `ceiling`). Also **note that** in this case, since both `min` and `max` are above 0, you could replace `floor` with `trunc` or `as.integer` too.

```
set.seed(42)
x = floor(runif(n = 1000000, min = 1, max = 52 + 1))
plot(prop.table(table(x)), las = 2, cex.axis = 0.75)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thanks. My error in using as.integer() lead me to the more interesting question.

Comment: This is problematic if you want a uniform distribution across the integers: `prop.table(table(round(runif(100000, 1, 10))))` shows (for example) that there's only half as much chance of getting either of the two extreme values.

Comment: @BenBolker, upon further investigation, it seems like either `floor` or `ceiling` with appropriate adjustment to the `min` and `max` in `runif` may be better: `plot(prop.table(table(floor(runif(10000, 1, 52+1)))), las = 2)`

Answer (score 2):

`as.integer(51.999)`

> 51

It is because how as.integer works.

If you want to draw from a discrete distribution, then use sample.  `runif` is not for discrete distributions.

Comment: `?runif` states that the function itself will not generate either of the extreme values, so it has nothing to do with `as.integer`

Comment: But as some point, shouldn't runif() return 52? But your point is taken about using as.integer(). I thought it rounded, when it in fact it just drops the decimals.

Comment: If you want to draw from a discrete distribution, then use sample.  `runif` is not for discrete distributions.

Comment: @useR `runif` generating any value is of 0 probability - not just the end values. OP try to convert a continuous distribution to a discrete one using `as.integer`.

Comment: My point is not that there is a greater than 0 chance that the extreme points would be generated, but that those extereme points are not even taken into consideration _by design_. See @Ben's answer.

Comment: Okay. My answer was actually the fact that unless the `runif` exactly give 52, the OP would not see 52 (i.e. 51.999 is still not 52).  Which is actually why what he tried to do does not work. Even if he gets 52 after running very large number of simulations, it is not what he wants do to.